# Verifying spectral norm

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

I was wondering how one could verify the relation that $||A||_2 = \sqrt{\rho(A^HA)}$ for matrices. I mean I have seen this so often, but never found a proof of it. Is there a smart way to do this quickly? Because only referring to the most basic properties of matrices seem to be not a good idea here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), let $A=USV^H$ be a SVD, where the singular values in $S=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ are arranged in descending order. Then $\sqrt{\rho(A^HA)}=\sqrt{\rho(S^HS)}=\sigma_1$. If you define $\|A\|_2$ as $\sigma_1$, you are done. If you define $\|A\|_2$ as $\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|$, it follows immediately that
$$\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|US(V^H)x\|_2=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|S(V^H)x\|_2=\max_{\|y\|_2=1}\|Sy\|_2=\sigma_1.$$

**Edit:** Alternatively, note that $A^HA$ is positive semidefinite because $x^H A^HAx=\|Ax\|_2^2\ge0$. Therefore it can be unitarily diagonalised as $U^HDU$, where $U$ is unitary and $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix. As the diagonal entries of $D$ are eigenvalues of $A^HA$, we have $\rho(A^HA)=\max_id_i$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
\|A\|_2 &= \max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2 = \sqrt{\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2^2}
 = \sqrt{\max_{\|x\|_2=1} x^H A^HAx}\\
&= \sqrt{\max_{\|x\|_2=1} (Ux)^H D(Ux)}
= \sqrt{\max_{\|y\|_2=1} y^H Dy}
=\sqrt{\max_id_i}=\sqrt{\rho(A^HA)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: yes, this is a smart way to do this! thanks

Comment: If we can not use SVD,how to prove that?

Comment: @Lisa See my new edit.